# Is it okay to make insignificant edits now that I have more rep?

Tags: discussion

While looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879746/memory-leak-in-class-constructor-of-c/24879806#24879806) answer I thought, I could reword this to make it use proper grammar. For example, "This makes it trivially obey the Rule of Three." would be "This makes it trivial to obey the Rule of Three." But this would indeed break from making edits significant, i.e.; tackle more than one issue.

But I don't get rep anymore for edits so no harm no foul right?

Comment: I would suppose as long as you don't abuse it it's fine.

Comment: An edit still bumps the answer and gives it more views most of the time so there is still a trade-off here. In my opinion edits that fix grammar in questions are significant though so by all means go for it.

Comment: I don't change an author's style or language preferences. The case you mentioned is a matter of personal preference/style. I do, however, correct typos, like I did for this very question.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: is that the case? "...trivially obey..." isn't correct is it?

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. But it looks like a personal style (way of speaking). Correcting it won't add any _significant value_ to the post, it is a fairly clear answer despite the improper grammer. Edits should be substantial, else we end up bumping too many posts if we edit trivial things. It's just a line that each editor draws for themselves - when to edit and when not to edit, @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: OK, I actually didn't know, or notice, that the edit bumps the question. Not in this case, but that *could* lead to answers of a lesser quality getting more attention. Will keep it in mind. @InfiniteRecursion

Comment: That sentence actually sounds correct to me. Then again, some would argue that I don't speak English. ;) In any case, I don't think it hurts the readability. Generally, I don't think there's clear consensus on how substantial edits should be. The barrier is certainly lower once you don't need reviews anymore. I'm generally more in the camp of making improvements, even if they are not very big. Still, this example looks too minor even for my taste. I think your energy would be better spent with posts that have multiple and more substantial problems. There are plenty of them!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion *grammar. Re. bumping, maybe we could have a privilege for a "minor edit" that doesn't bump a question? Especially now we're more free to edit without risking bumping a post to CW status.

Comment: "This makes it trivially obey the Rule of Three." and "This makes it trivial to obey the Rule of Three." are both correct English sentences, with different meanings. Don't change one into the other unless you're confident that the poster meant the one he didn't write! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879746/memory-leak-in-class-constructor-of-c/24879806#24879806) the one that was written makes more sense in context, however *it* should be *them*, refering to the classes of the previous sentence. [ell.se] can help you with such topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No foul, but remember that every edit you make triggers an inbox notification for the author. Some folks are on a crusade to make sure "its" and "it's" are used properly on the site, and bless 'em for it, because so many folks get that wrong. Others are on a quest to eliminate unnecessarily complex compound sentences by breaking them into several.

Just use common sense, and respect the voice, tone and intentions of the original author. Don't add emphasis that wasn't their own, leave intentional alliteration and cleverly placed humor where it is. It's their voice, their preference when it comes to indentation and formatting, their contribution to the site. Your edits no longer need to be peer-reviewed, so you're not tasking folks with minutia - feel free to improve that which you can which needs it. Respect their right to roll your edit back.

Just be respectful, and use common sense.