# Is it a minor edit if you add a tag that makes the question much more obvious to anyone skimming through the feed?

Tags: discussion

Many many times I've been scrolling through the question feed and see questions that have big chunks of code, using API's or frameworks of some sort that include **only** the tag for that API or framework.

If you then add a tag to the question that tells you what the language is at a glance, is that too minor an edit? Or if the only tag is the language and there is no tag for the API or framework, which is coincidentily the meat of the question.. Would adding a tag for the API or framework be too minor an edit?

I only ask because a few times now I've had people comment saying "Please don't make insubstantial edits" and I'm sat here thinking: But adding that 4 letter tag actually makes it easier for people looking for the issue to find it, surely that means it's worth it?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526936/achievements-and-acl) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527442/forcerebootcondition-syntax) are examples of such questions (I edited them to include the tags, but I don't think I was "reprimanded" by anyone for them)

Comment: Generally a post missing an important tag has other things wrong with it that need correcting as well. Do you have an example of a question where the *only* thing wrong is a missing tag?

Comment: Concerning "missing" tags, I would say it depends on the existing tags. Two examples: there is no much need to add `[javascript]` to questions tagged `[jquery]` since the latter more or less implies the former. On the other hand, questions tagged `[gtk]` or `[zeromq]` can benefit from a language tag since there are so many bindings.

Comment: I added two examples to my question :)

Comment: There's spelling and grammar problems with both of those questions, and I have a feeling the first should be closed (too broad?) - I'd expect tag-only suggested edits on both of those to get rejected as too minor because they wouldn't be addressing those other issues.

Comment: So if a question is shall we say _questionable_ then it's better to attempt to address all the issues or not bother with an edit?

Comment: @JonK, then I would suggest we remove the feature that allows us to only edit tags in a question. It gives the impression tag edits (for categorization) are somewhat complementary but distinct from content edits.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I may be part of a minority but I like to read interesting questions (or at least questions that seem interesting), but I do this while at work as part of a microbreak while some automated tests or something run, so while I'm happy to make an edit that in my opinion makes a difference and requires not as much effort.. I don't really have the time to sit and make huge edits to questions but I want to help and feel this is how I can?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't think it should be removed, but perhaps suggested edits shouldn't be permitted to only change tags. Leave tag-only edits to the 2k users who can edit the tags directly.

Comment: @Stormie, I personally always considered tag edits as a "special case", but I may not be in line with the current community consensus, so YMMV :)

Comment: @JonK, isn't that feature already restricted to 2K+ users? I seem to remember it is.

Comment: After reading [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251262/3053362) answer to a similar question, I think the knowledge has clicked. Thank you for your comments though :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi 2k users can edit the tags without going to the full edit screen, but suggested edits are currently allowed to only change tags (unless that's changed in the last month or so).

Comment: Just for the record, I was the one today to warn you about that, since it wasn't the first time I saw you edit only for tags when other obvious things needed improvements that wouldn't take more than a minute to correct. Seems you edit while I review edits. I rarely warn unless I notice a repeating pattern.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That's fine, you're being helpful to me. I was only wondering whether it was worth me making, what I feel are the edits I can in the time I have or not. After all, I only want to be useful :)

Comment: Adding language tags helps experts find the question easier, even if it's tagged with a specific framework, the issue could be something minor that someone familiar with the language could help with.

Comment: I frequently add language tags in questions where I don't feel I'm confident to make more extensive edits. For instance, I'm not a Java programmer, but I can recognize a question that should have the java tag, so I add it when it's missing.

Comment: Also, if we want to encourage people to make more substantive edits when fixing tags, we should get rid of the "Edit Tags" button, which makes very easy to make quick tag fixes.

Comment: this is very common, and whenever I see it, I add the tag. It's really needed. For example, if the solution requires JQuery and the question doesn't have that tag, people with JQuery knowledge may not see it

Comment: @Barmer, because of your 2k+ rep adding appropriate tags is OK in an otherwise [insignificant edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266335/is-it-okay-to-make-insignificant-edits-now-that-i-have-more-rep) but bad advice for lower rep folks. There are so many tag only edits coming through many of them redundant to others. An edit is either valid or not; tag only(s) are too minor. If there's not enough to make it valid, comment the fact. We're padding rep otherwise. I decline every one I come across.